# How to reference an exported namespace from the root in a typescript type?

Tags: typescript

The following typescript code compiles:

```js
namespace A {
    export interface X { inner: string }
}

namespace B {
    namespace A {
        interface Y { inner: globalThis.A.X }
    }
}
```

Note that I need to use `globalThis` to refer to `A.X`, as the reference otherwise gets mixed up with the `A` in `B.A`.

However, this does not compile for an *exported* namespace `A`:

```
export namespace A {
    export interface X { inner: string }
}

namespace B {
    namespace A {
        interface Y { inner: globalThis.A.X }
    }
}
```

```
// error: Namespace 'globalThis' has no exported member 'A'.
```

Is there a way in this scenario to refer to `A.X` from within `B.A`?

Answer (score 1):

Remember this from the old days?

```
var _this = this;
```

We've got that here as well:

```
export namespace A {
    export interface X { inner: string }
}

import _A = A;
namespace B {
    namespace A {
        interface Y { inner: _A.X }
    }
}
```

`import _X = X;` is the import of a namespace, but it also works as an alias.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wy63gw)